# Como Inserir um Slider no meu site

Tags: jquery, css

Estou desenvolvendo um site e gostaria de adicionar um slider simples, porém, elegante.

Existe algum plugin, de preferência que seja jQuery, que me permita criar um slider como o [deste site](http://www.resellerclub.com/)?

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/anythingslider/

Comment: Muito obrigado @Sergio muito útil seu comentário! ;)

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/